# Union of n-polytopes

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I am looking to find the union of two polytopes of arbitrary dimension. Here's a simple way to generate convex polytopes:

```
points = np.random.rand(n_vertices, n_dimensions)
hull = scipy.spatial.ConvexHull(points)
print(points, hull.simplices)
```

A polytope then looks like points, and simplices, for example:

```
array([[0.62092, 0.82149, 0.23474, 0.56461],
       [0.70291, 0.46087, 0.77879, 0.03314],
       [0.92248, 0.46931, 0.84108, 0.85117],
       [0.74662, 0.39989, 0.74759, 0.76127],
       [0.90351, 0.70135, 0.16062, 0.79807]]), 
array([[4, 3, 2, 0],
       [1, 3, 2, 0],
       [1, 4, 2, 0],
       [1, 4, 3, 0],
       [1, 4, 3, 2]])
```

How can I compute the union of n-polytopes of arbitrary dimension? I realize the output can be concave, so it's not just the convex hull of their vertices.

I tried to find this functionality in [shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/), [polytope](https://tulip-control.github.io/polytope/) and [Polylib](https://www.irisa.fr/polylib/), but no joy.

Blender takes care of the 3D case, which looks like this:[image]

Comment: I hope it's just a question of finding simplex intersections and subdividing them. It's for a polytope packing dataset for research, where I would also like to include a higher-dimensional task.

Comment: In order to find the union of two polytopes, the intersecting simplices (faces) need to be updated.

Comment: They become new, different simplices. For example: The union of two overlapping triangles of edge length 1 becomes a polygon where some edges have length different to 1.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, do you believe you have an idea how to proceed? I'm keen to find anything that leads to an answer.